# Почему происходит отправка пустых данных на сервер?

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

У меня есть 5 текстовых полей и кнопка, отправляющая введенные данные в понятной для сервера форме. Проблема в том, что данные на сервере пусты. Не пойму, куда они делись? При клике на кнопку происходит execute(); этого AsyncTask -

```
private class AddG extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;
    OutputStream output;
    InputStream input;
    String data;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            //Берём данные
            name_data = name_edit.getText().toString();
            login_data  = login_edit.getText().toString();
            password_data   = password_edit.getText().toString();
            info_data = info_edit.getText().toString();
            adress_data = adress_edit.getText().toString();

            //строим отправительные данные
            String post_url = server_name + "/access/index.php?add";
            data = "name="
                 + name_data 
                 + "&adress=" 
                 + adress_data
                 + "&password="
                 + password_data
                 + "&login="
                 + login_data
                 + "&info="
                 + info_data;

            //пичкаем коннект
            URL url = new URL(post_url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)");
            conn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(8000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            //создаём туннель к серверу и отправляем данные
            output = conn.getOutputStream();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            output.close();
            conn.connect();

            //открываем туннель для ответа от сервера и пихаем его в result
            input = conn.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `content-type` должен быть один. в вашем случае это `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Вторя установка скорей всего заменит первую, но в вашем случае неверно использовать ни `application/form-data`, ни `application/json`. Не знаю может так и задумано, что потоки закрываются до conn.connect(), но по мне это очень странно. Может ничего и в принципе не посылается на сервер, раз всё закрыто до connect? `url` перепроверьте, может не тот адрес получается. И что сервер принимает запросы на `/access/index.php?add` Как на сервере данные извлекаются из запроса?

Comment: @Sergey, url правильный, getResponseCode возвращает 200 и как бы в ссылках я не путаюсь) насчет сервера не знаю, им занимается профессионал. скинул мне макет данных вида name=f&adress=h&password=v&login=x&info=q и все